# Alternative to onload for elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there an attribute that I can place JavaScript into that executes as soon as the element is finished parsing by the browser?

In effect, I would like to have an `onload` and be able to pass `this` as a parameter to a function.

The only work around I have found is specifying an id on the element and passing that to a function (within a SCRIPT tag) immediately after my element.

I'd like this:

```
<div onload="doSomething(this);"></div>
```

Instead of this:

```
<div id="myId"></div>
<script>doSomething("myId");</script>
```

Also, the solution should be cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not admit to this openly, but the only reason you 'd want to do something like that is in order to iterate over a number of elements and perform the same kind of processing on all of them. If so, you are headed down the wrong path.

Simply give all these elements a common class and then use e.g. [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) to find them and do what you need. You can do this when the `load` event triggers for the body element.

Comment: Agreed, I don't admit that but you are right. That is what I want to do. I'll add a jQuery tag since I am not opposed to using it for this problem.

Comment: @Matthew: `document.querySelectorAll` is not dependent on jQuery at all, so you don't *have* to use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

For normal page loads I don't believe there is that level of granularity. You can detect when ALL of the HTML is loaded and when is has ALL finished rendering. Most people just process things when the page is ready and iterate over the elements in-turn.